# rhub compilation warning on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package, cran

We are developing an R package that contains compiled code (using [Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html)). We check the package builds on [rhub](https://github.com/r-hub/rhub) (to test builds on multiple platforms) with `check_for_cran()` function.

For Ubuntu 16.04, we get the following warning

```
* checking compilation flags used ... WARNING
Compilation used the following non-portable flag(s):
  '-Wdate-time' '-Werror-format-security' '-Wformat'
```

We currently do not have a `Makevars` file in the `src` sub directory. To suppress the warnings, we added the `-Wall` flag in the Makevars file, which results in the following warning

```
* checking compilation flags in Makevars ... WARNING
Variables overriding user/site settings:
  CFLAGS: -Wall
```

We tried multiple settings of Makevars, but could not get rid of these warnings. We would appreciate any help.

1. For submission on [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/), we need to be able to build the package without any warnings.

Comment: It comes from the system-wide `Makeconf` file; you cannot override it. CRAN uses a different machine / setup so the warnings at RHub are not indicative of CRAN warnings.

Comment: See also https://github.com/r-hub/rhub/issues/264

Comment: In the R code in the tools package, there is some provision for passing a list of additional 'known' flags via an environment variable.  As these flags come from the Debian compiler defaults, I should probably try to tell the package to ignore these.  But I haven't had a chance yet to work this out.  Help welcome...